# When i click to run as administrator it dont actually runs as administrator

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions, administrator

Hi i was going to install something but that something has to be started as administrator so i...

Left click > run as administrator. Then the .exe started in normal mode. Then when i tried with other programs and executables they all start normally.

**Basically, when i click to run as administrator, it doesnt ask my password to run it as administrator, it just starts normally, not in administrator. What can i do? Tried to put the ''run this in administrator '' in properties but still dont ask me for permission**

Comment: Is the user that you are using have admin privileges?
When you select the exe file, click Shift with the left click, you should be able to see the command : run as user. Click on it and enter the admin credentials.

Comment: No its in standard, when i try to change it to admin, it just goes back to standard, i guess it is cause it should be asking permissions to change that, but the problem its that, stuff its not asking my permission anymore, when i click run as administrator it just runs normally. Know what else i can do?

Comment: don't you have an admin account on this PC?

Comment: Yes i Shift + Right click > start as another user and logged into the admin one but still dont works since the program says that its needed to run as admin. The main problem is that i changed nothing, it just changed by itself. What i need its so that when i click ''run as admin'', it asks me for my password again like it did for 2 years until 30 mins ago :D, after that i can directly make this one the admin one. Do you know how i can make it ask for password again like it always did before it changed by itself?

Comment: Are you sure the other account has admin rights? I've seen this kind of behaviour... and what I found out is this happens if there are NO admin account present in the PC (so it won't prompt you for password for ANY account.. simply because no account has admin rights).

Comment: Yes the other one is admin, and as i said. I changed nothing! From arround 2 years to 1h ago this one wasnt admin, so when i needed to admin i just had to click run as admin, put the password and everything continues perfectly. But for some reason now when i click ''run as admin'', no password asked and also dont start as admin, its just like i clicked open, not in admin, just normal

Comment: What setting is UAC? If disabled, there would be no prompt.

Answer (score 0):

in windows 7,8,10 by default administrator account is in disable mode

so first enable the administrator account by using the computer management\users

then try as administrator it will work

Comment: I had this pc for like 2 years and it was always on admin mode, and even if it wasnt if i clicked ''run as administrator'' it should ask for the password when there's one. So what should i do?

Comment: Also i tried to change the account from standard to admin but i cant, when i click it i guess it should be asking me my password to do it, but since it doesnt, after clicking on admin and accepting it just goes back to standard since im not putting password, simply cause it doesnt ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your UAC settings have been changed.

This might have been due to update installed lately, but most probable scenario is that you installed a trojan on your machine.

I think I can safely assume that some time ago (within an hour or so of your issue starting) you installed something and then you had a notification that your UAC settings have been changed...

I've seen that behaviour on my own computer - usually after installing applications downloaded from questionable sources.

So my suggestions are obvious: re-set your UAC to max and then run every security scan you can grab on short notice.

EDIT: after some thinking it's possible you have UAC completely disabled. I would posit that based on question and comments:

1. you have the same behaviour as both admin and standard user and
2. programs that need elevation run correctly.